# in querySelector: how to get the first and get the last elements? what traversal order is used in the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, html

in a div, have elements (not necessarily 2nd generation) with attribute `move_id`.

First, would like most direct way of fetching first and last elements of set

tried getting first and last via:

```
var first = div.querySelector('[move_id]:first');
var last  = div.querySelector('[move_id]:last');
```

this bombs because :first and :last were wishful thinking on my part (?)

cannot use the Array methods of `querySelectorAll` since `NodeList` is not an Array:

```
var first = (div.querySelectorAll('[move_id]'))[0];
var last  = (div.querySelectorAll('[move_id'])).pop();
```

this bombs because `NodeList` does not have method `pop()`

(yes, one could could use Array methods on top of the NodeList:

```
var first = div.querySelector('[move_id]');
var last = Array.prototype.pop.call(div.querySelectorAll('[move_id']));
```

this works, and is what I'm using now, but thinking there has to be something more direct that I'm simply missing)

Second, need to verify that the elements are listed by pre-oder depth-first traversal as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Answer (score 150, accepted):

To access the first and last elements, try.

```
var nodes = div.querySelectorAll('[move_id]');
var first = nodes[0];
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
```

For robustness, add index checks.

Yes, the order of nodes is pre-order depth-first. DOM's `document order` is defined as,

> There is an ordering, document order, defined on all the nodes in the document corresponding to the order in which the first character of the XML representation of each node occurs in the XML representation of the document after expansion of general entities. Thus, the document element node will be the first node. Element nodes occur before their children. Thus, document order orders element nodes in order of the occurrence of their start-tag in the XML (after expansion of entities). The attribute nodes of an element occur after the element and before its children. The relative order of attribute nodes is implementation-dependent.

Comment: re traversal - thanks - I admire those who can remember and find the support doc for these issues

Comment: but as for code, for my own sense of aesthetics, prefer my solution: it doesn't need to declare the nodes variable for example, but this is simply personal preferences.  what I was hoping is that some there was some correct usage of :first and :last that I was missing.

Comment: Sad this is a code solution, not selector solution. You can use `:first-of-type` pseudoblock if you select a subset of tags by name, but that's not always possible.

Answer (score 25):

Adding to the answers here a solution (a bit different to the others proposed):

Using the `:last-of-type` selector to get the last element of a certain specific ***tag*** name.

[Array method `at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is also helpful in combination with `querySelectorAll`, but it requires to destruct the result, to get a "real" array, because `querySelectorAll` doesn't have the `at` method at its disposal (so sad...)

```js
console.log(
  ":last-of-type:",
  document.querySelector('mark:last-of-type') // <---- 
)

console.log(
  ":last-child:",
  document.querySelector('mark:last-child')
)

console.log(
  "querySelectorAll + at:",
  [...document.querySelectorAll('mark')].at(-1)
)
```

```html
<p>
this is <mark>highlighted</mark> and this is <mark>is also</mark> but <strong>not this</strong>.
</p>
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is, again, relative to the parent element, and may return multiple results depending on query construction.

Answer (score 9):

Example to get the **last** input element:

`document.querySelector(".groups-container >div:last-child input")`

Comment: Actually it doesn't. This answer only gets `INPUT:first-child` from `DIV:last-child`. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/nqtpk5gd/1/

Answer (score 5):

```
let first = div.querySelector('[move_id]');
let last  = Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('[move_id]')).pop();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34025497)

Answer (score 2):

#### Use element.firstElementChild and element.lastElementChild

If you want to get the *first* child ***element***, use: [**`node.firstElementChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild). (if you want the first child, even if it's a non-element like text, then use: [**`node.firstChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)).

If you want to get the *last* child ***element***, use: [**`node.lastElementChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild). (again, if you want to select a non-element child, like text, use use: [**`node.lastChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild)).

#### MDN WebDocs Description

From the above-linked MDN webdocs:

> **firstElementChild** — The Element.firstElementChild read-only property returns an element's first child Element, or null if there are no child elements.
>
> **lastElementChild** — The Element.lastElementChild read-only property returns an element's last child Element, or null if there are no child elements.

#### Wide Browser Support

`firstChild` and `lastChild` have ***extremely wide browser support***.

Supported in:

- Chrome — Version 1
- Edge — Version 12
- Firefox — Version 1
- Internet Explorer — Version 6
- Opera — Version 12.1
- Safari — Version 1

#### Working Demo — firstElementChild & lastElementChild

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById('my-div');
mydiv.firstElementChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
mydiv.lastElementChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
    <p>My first paragraph!</p>
    <p>Here is an intermediate paragraph!</p>
    <p>Here is another intermediate paragraph!</p>
    <p>Here is yen another intermediate paragraph!</p>
    <p>My last paragraph!</p>
</div>
```

#### Working Demo — firstChild & lastChild

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById('my-div');
mydiv.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
mydiv.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

```html
<div id="my-div"><p>My first paragraph!</p><p>Here is an intermediate paragraph!</p><p>Here is another intermediate paragraph!</p><p>Here is yen another intermediate paragraph!</p><p>My last paragraph!</p></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is the best than all of the upvoted answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first and last element directly.

```js
//-- first element
console.log( document.querySelector("#my-div").querySelectorAll( "p" )[0] );
//-- last element
console.log( document.querySelector("#my-div").querySelectorAll( "p" )[document.querySelector("#my-div").querySelectorAll( "p" ).length-1] );
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
  <p>My first paragraph!</p>
  <p>Here is an intermediate paragraph!</p>
  <p>Here is another intermediate paragraph!</p>
  <p>Here is yen another intermediate paragraph!</p>
  <p>My last paragraph!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const first = div.querySelector('[move_id]');
const last  = div.querySelector('[move_id]:last-child');
```