# Using querySelector() to obtain last td element

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have a variable which is a node from the dom. I've managed to get all the way down to close to where I want to be:

```
myvar.querySelector('.tblItinPriceSummary tr')
```

Gives me this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Subtotal</td>
    <td align="right">$189.00</td>
</tr>
```

What I want is the textContent of the second td $189.

Is there anything I can add inside of querySelector so that I can append it with .textContent to get this piece of data?

Comment: linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5684811/104380

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could either use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) or [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) to access the last `td` element within the parent.

```
document.querySelector('.tblItinPriceSummary tr td:last-child').textContent;
```