# Javascript get last element from nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following html structure:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>  // 1
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div> // 2
        <div></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div> // n
        <div></div>
    </div> // <---- return this one
  </div>

  <div></div>
</div>
```

How can I use the JS DOM query to return the last `div` element marked in the above structure?

Comment: Try: giving the div an id then use Document.getElementById()

Comment: I am trying to dynamically get the text from the google meet captions and those elements don't have a fixed selector

Comment: You are able to use [css selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398924/using-queryselector-to-obtain-last-td-element) using `querySelector`. In your case something like  `document.querySelector('div > div > div:last-of-type')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using querySelector() to obtain last td element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398924/using-queryselector-to-obtain-last-td-element)

Comment: @Lain that query is returning the last div from the #1 marked in my example

Comment: Depends on your use-case. Might be `document.querySelector('body > div > div > div:last-of-type')` in your actual code. As long as you get the idea, you are good to go. Be aware that `querySelector` returns the first match if there are several ones.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! Try it this way (using xpath):

```js
result = document.evaluate(
    '(//div//div[./div])[last()]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
  );
  alert(result.snapshotItem(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>  // 1
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div> // 2
        <div></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div> // return me
        <div>child of return me </div>
    </div> // ---- return this one
  </div>

  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) together with [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild). I added the `id`s so that you can see it gets the correct element but you don't actually need to have the `id`s to get the job done.

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('div > div');
console.log(parent.lastElementChild);
console.log(parent.lastElementChild.innerText);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="first">
      <div>First Text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      <div>Second Text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="last">
      <div>Last Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div></div>
</div>
```