# How would I know when I'm iterating over the last object in a DOM collection with for...of in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to iterate through a collection of DOM elements (as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Iterating_over_a_DOM_collection)

```
let articleParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll("article > p");

for (let paragraph of articleParagraphs) {
  paragraph.classList.add("read");
}
```

How would I detect which object in the collection I'm currently looping through? And most importantly, how would I know when I'm currently looking at the last object?

Comment: You don't know. If you need that, you can use `.forEach()`.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684811/in-queryselector-how-to-get-the-first-and-get-the-last-elements-what-traversal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable to the last paragraph in the list.

```
var lastParagraph = articleParagraphs[articleParagraphs.length-1];
for (let paragraph of articleParagraphs) {
    paragraph.classList.add("read");
    if (paragraph == lastParagraph) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me. I suppose if I need to know the position of each and every object that I'd need to use `.forEach()` instead?

Comment: Yes, or `for (let i = 0; i < articleParagraphs.length; i++)`